# Is it possible to create an audio-book for very old text/book?

Tags: audiobook

There are a few books that are at least 100 years old and without an audio book format. Is it legally possible to do the voice for it and sell it on audible?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that there is not a version? Have you tried [LibriVox](https://librivox.org/)? If there isn't a version, you have to ask yourself why and would anyone want it.

Otherwise, as far as I know, if it is out of copyright, you can record a version.

Comment: I definitely recommend using Librivox.  You can recruit others to do different chapters, if you want.  You also get proof-listeners, to be sure you haven't skipped lines or anything. (You can ask for pronunciation correction or not -- it's up to you.)

Answer (score 2):

If the book is old enough that the copyright has expired, this is completely legal. The length of copyright protection has changed over the years, but anything published before 1923 in the U.S. is now "public domain". For anything published after 1977, copyright is good for life of the author plus 70 years. There are various rules for anonymous works, works published by multiple authors, works that list an organization as the author, etc.

Comment: Can you do an audio book as a summarised layman's version regarding a recent book?

Comment: If by "summarized" you mean that you would include large amounts of the original text, but not all of it, like you're going to leave out half of the original text but keep half, then no, you can't do this without getting permission from the copyright owner. You'd still be copying large amounts of someone else's text. If you mean you're going to rewrite it in your own words, like "Hamlet begins with Hamlet meeting the ghost of his father ...", then as long as you don't use any but a few snippets of the original text, you're ok.

Comment: great follow up comment! Since there are some interesting books that people will only read/listen to if it takes a small amount of their time, a summarised version will be good for them. I will just write 3-4 page summaries of each chapter of some important history books, not including original text sections. Thanks